# How to test if two RMSE are significantly different?

Tags: statistical-significance, rms, diebold-mariano-test

Say I have two models for a regression task and from each model I get a RMSE. One RMSE is smaller than the other, however I wish to test if the difference is statistically significant in order to be able to say that one model is better than the other. How can I do it?

Comment: Are the models based on the same data with exactly the same response variable?  Please search our site (or anywhere else) for "overfitting" for some important considerations that will show you cannot compare models just by comparing RMSEs.

Comment: Both models are trained with the same data available for both. I’ve taken certain measures to avoid overfitting (like splitting the data in training and testing subsets, and dos kg cross validation, since the dataset is small).

Comment: AIC or BIC or even R^2 are used for comparing models based on same data. However, you should forget about testing for statistical significance of the difference between RMSE of the two models, that are based on the same data. This just makes no sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To test whether two (root) mean squared prediction errors are significantly different, the standard test is the Diebold-Mariano test ([Diebold & Mariano, 1995, *Journal of Business and Econonomic Statistics*](https://doi.org/10.1080/07350015.1995.10524599)). We have a [diebold-mariano](/questions/tagged/diebold-mariano) tag, which may be useful. I also recommend [Diebold's (2015, *Journal of Business and Econonomic Statistics*)](https://doi.org/10.1080/07350015.2014.983236) personal perspective on uses and abuses twenty years later.

Comment: The Diebold-Mariano test seems specialized for time-series forecasting, but adapting it for a set of independent observation seems straightforward: the calculation of the variance just becomes simpler. It seems like there should be a name for this simpler version?

Comment: @PaulHarrison: it may well be that there is no test for this simpler approach, because it just turns into a straightforward t- or z-test...